# How to add new examples to already made dummy variables in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dummy-variable

I am building on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68325491/how-to-create-binary-representations-of-words-in-pandas-column).

I already constructed dummy variables, however I want to add new examples, but I want them to fit the previous dummies.

They could have new words, those should not be included.

```
0    ["AC","BB"]
1    ["AD","CB", "FF"]
2    ["AA","CC"]
3    ["CA","BB"]
4    ["AA"]
```

The dummies are already created:

```
     AC    BB    AD  
0     1     1     0
1     0     0     1
   ......
```

I than have new data-frame that I want construct into dummies, but I want it to fit the previous dummy dataframe.

Comment: Is possible see how looks expected ouput?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's imagine those two Series:

```
s1 = pd.Series(map(lambda x: x.split(), ['AC BB', 'AD CB FF', 'AA CC', 'CA BB', 'AA']))
s2 = pd.Series(map(lambda x: x.split(), ['XX ZZ', 'AA YY']), index=[5,6])
```

```
>>> s1
0        [AC, BB]
1    [AD, CB, FF]
2        [AA, CC]
3        [CA, BB]
4            [AA]

>>> s2
5    [XX, ZZ]
6    [AA, YY]
```

Then you concatenate the dummies using:

```
pd.concat([pd.get_dummies(s1.explode()).sum(level = 0),
           pd.get_dummies(s2.explode()).sum(level = 0)]).fillna(0).astype(int)
```

output:

```
   AA  AC  AD  BB  CA  CB  CC  FF  XX  YY  ZZ
0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0
2   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
3   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
4   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
5   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1
6   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
```

In case you have duplicated indexes between the two datasets (e.g., use `index=[5,4]` in s2), you need to add `.groupby(level=0).max()` to merge the observations:

```
(pd.concat([pd.get_dummies(s1.explode()).sum(level = 0),
            pd.get_dummies(s2.explode()).sum(level = 0)])
   .fillna(0).astype(int)
   .groupby(level=0).max()
)
```

Comment: Thanks. In the end I only want the columns that are already in the first df. I saved the columns and than made .loc selection to to do this. THank you anyway.