# Creating dummy variables out of list of words with optimal space allocation

Tags: python, pandas, dummy-variable

I already have the solution:

```
dummies = pd.get_dummies(df["R"].str.findall("([A-Z][a-z]+)").explode()).sum(level = 0)
```

I am dealing with a very large dataset. I found using explode makes the intermediate dataframe(before the sum) around 5 times larger than the finished product.

I am struggling for RAM space. Is there to do this more efficiently in terms of memory?

Comment: Can you tell a bit more of what you are trying to do? If you only need a sum, there might be another solution (but I’m not sure that I understand what you need)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68325491/how-to-create-binary-representations-of-words-in-pandas-column This is my original question.